# webpack - imports-loader vs ProvidePlugin

Tags: webpack, imports-loader

Could someone please show me the differences between the two?

I know that the imports-loader will insert a require into the asking module and the ProvidePlugin will make an instance of, say Jquery, if the symbol $ is matched.

But apart from that are anything else that make these 2 different from one another?